# Stripe Get Name from Session

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a session:

```
 const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: converted_items,
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: process.env.URL + "/success",
    cancel_url: process.env.URL + "/order-page.html"
 });
```

And I am trying to retrieve the name from the session by getting the latest session, and accessing the customer object which contains the name, which returns null.

```
const sesh = await stripe.checkout.sessions.list({
    limit: 1,
  });
  console.log(sesh.data[0].customer)
  const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(sesh.data[0].customer);
  console.log(customer)
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do banks not give out that information when people make payments.  I am trying to create an online ordering system for a restaurant and their names are very important to the ordering system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Banks will not reveal the name of a customer during a payment. If you need their name you have to collect it explicitly in Checkout instead. The idea here is to enable billing address collection so that Checkout always requires all that information from the customer including their name.

This is done by passing `billing_address_collection: 'required'` on `Session` creation ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-billing_address_collection)).

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ["card"],
  line_items: converted_items,
  mode: "payment",
  success_url: process.env.URL + "/success",
  cancel_url: process.env.URL + "/order-page.html",
  billing_address_collection: 'required',    
});
```

Comment: I added the following attribute that you said and made another payment and checked on stripe whether they stored the name and they did not.

Comment: The information would live on the `PaymentMethod` associated with the payment and not the customer itself

Comment: Would you mind writing out the code so I can see how it works?  I am new to stripe.

Comment: Could you also include how I would be getting the name from the PaymentMethod object?  That's the part that I am having trouble on.

Comment: When the Session is completed you can retrieve it and look at the payment method directly and all its properties. This is done using the Expand feature as documented here:  https://stripe.com/docs/expand#multiple-properties Once you have the PaymentIntent you can access the underlying charge and all its details via `session.payment_intent.charges.data[0].payment_method_details.billing_details` for example